# Tensorflow DNN with tf-idf sparse matrix

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets

Trying to implement tesorflow DNN for text classification.

tf-idf sparse IV:

```
X_train_sam:
<31819x3122 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'with 610128 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

labels as DV:

```
y_train_sam.values:array(['mexican', 'mexican', 'italian', ..., 'chinese', 'italian','italian'], dtype=object)
```

Converting sparse to tensor using following piece:

```
def convert_sparse_matrix_to_sparse_tensor(X):
    coo = X.tocoo()
    indices = np.mat([coo.row, coo.col]).transpose()
    return tf.SparseTensorValue(indices, coo.data, coo.shape)

 X_train_sam = convert_sparse_matrix_to_sparse_tensor(X_train_sam)
```

Preparing data for modeling

```
def train_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((features, labels))
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat().batch(batch_size)
    return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

inp = train_input_fn(X_train_sam,y_train_sam.values,batch_size=1000)
```

Applying DNN Classifier

```
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=[float]*X_train_sam.dense_shape[1],
    hidden_units=[10, 10],
    n_classes=len(y_train_sam.unique()))

classifier.train(input_fn=lambda:inp)
```

Getting following error:

```
ValueError: features should be a dictionary of `Tensor`s. Given type: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensorValue'>
```

Please give some pointers, i am new to ML and tensorflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in your code on this line

```
classifier.train(input_fn=lambda:inp)
```

`lambda:inp` is supposed to be a dictionary or you mean an anonymous function?
From the documentation at

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier

> input_fn: Input function returning a tuple of: features - Tensor or
>   dictionary of string feature name to Tensor. labels - Tensor or
>   dictionary of Tensor with labels.

So you need a function that returns a tuple, not a single value...

Comment: Thanks it worked but labels need to be simple integer numpy array

Comment: That is not always the case. What do you mean exactly? Are you still having problems with labels?

Comment: Having the same problem as OP, could someone expand on the answer to give an example of input_fn that would return a tuple of classes and labels that would be correctly formatted?